# Как исключить папку для deny from all в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть файл .htaccess с таким кодом:

```
# line below if for Apache 2.4
<ifModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</ifModule>

# line below if for Apache 2.2
<ifModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    deny from all
    Satisfy All
</ifModule>
```

Он находится в папке /core.
Как в этом .htaccess добавить исключение для папки /core/components/calc? Чтобы к ней не применялись данные директивы. Чтобы к ней был доступ.